# Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following warning

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined
>   component.

this is my code

```
var React = require('react');
import DetectUtil from 'pofod/detectUtil';
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent,MobileComponent) {
    class Subscription extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                ExternalComponent:innerWidth>1023?WrappedComponent:MobileComponent
            }
            this.getPageLangParams=this.getPageLangParams.bind(this);
            this.MonitorSize = this.MonitorSize.bind(this);
        }
        getPageLangParams () {
            var query=this.props.location?(this.props.location.query?this.props.location.query:{}):{};
            var lang=this.props.lang||query.lang||DetectUtil.languageFamily()||'zh';
            return lang;
        }
        MonitorSize(){
            this.setState({
                ExternalComponent:innerWidth>1023?WrappedComponent:MobileComponent
            })
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            window.addEventListener('resize',this.MonitorSize)
        }
        componentWillMount(){
            window.removeEventListener('resize',this.MonitorSize)
        }
        render(){
            let lang = this.getPageLangParams();
            let ExternalComponent = this.state.ExternalComponent;
            return (
                <ExternalComponent lang={lang}/>
            )
        }
    }
    return Subscription;
}

module.exports = withSubscription;
```

Answer (score 1):

You confused componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount.

EventListener is removing on componentWillMount but you should remove it right before unmounting e.g. componentWillUnmount.

So when component is unmounted the MonitorSize stops triggering.
Here is how it should be:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
     window.removeEventListener('resize',this.MonitorSize)
}
```